# How do we pronounce month's? I mean apostrophe s after th?

Tags: pronunciation, th, consonant-clusters

How do we pronounce apostrophe s after *th*? For example *month's*? And how do we pronounce *deaths*?

Answer (score 1):

The presence or absence of an **apostrophe** makes no difference.

When I say 'th', my tongue is curled up at the sides. To change the sound to 's' I simply flatten it.